# How does the invocation of this function work?

Tags: javascript

```
function functionOne(x){console.log(x);};

function functionTwo(var1) {

};
functionTwo(functionOne(2));
```

why does functionTwo work there ? it doesn't suppose  work, does it? 
because there is not an operation.

Comment: `functionTwo` does nothing but you're also *directly* calling `functionOne`. There is no callback here.

Comment: This isn't really a question about callbacks, it's just a question about function invocation. A callback is a function **reference** that is passed as an argument.

Comment: @ScottMarcus It's a misunderstanding about callbacks, as the asker believes they are passing a callback function as `var1` which will call `functionOne(2)` when called.

Comment: @Klaycon I understand. That's why I added the comment - - to clarify it.

Answer (score 5):

> functionTwo(functionOne(2));

This means "immediately call `functionOne`, passing in 2. Then pass the result into `functionTwo`". So `functionOne` does its thing, logging out 2, and then returns `undefined`. And then `undefined` is passed into `functionTwo`.

Instead, if you're trying to experiment with callbacks you need to pass a function in, as in:

```
functionTwo(() => functionOne(2));
```

Once you do that, you'll no longer see a console.log unless you add some code to `functionTwo`.